# How to take images from api and put into drawable folder

Tags: android, android-studio, drawable

My question title itself is very precise.

Is there a way by which we can parse images from JSON api and put image in drawable folder.

My requirement is like I have to make logos and asset images dynamic.

I cant keep static images in drawable folder.

Note : I am using Android Studio for development.

Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: resources are read-only ... putting something to res folder at runtime is not possible

Comment: any solution for this problem then.

Comment: You can save images to app private storage to use within your application but this directory is separate from your drawable folder - See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/q/26612102/3416642

Comment: Refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38005996/5733111)

Answer (score 0):

You can't put downloaded image in Drawable folder. Drawable folder is accessible only in IDE, instead you can create local database and save your downloaded image in your database. There are certain libraries for loading your image from server / URL in minimum time with low cache as follows :

1) **Picasso** - https://github.com/square/picasso

2) **Glide** - https://github.com/bumptech/glide

3) **UIL** (Universal Image Loader) - https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Also check **Comparison** here - [Picasso v/s Imageloader v/s Fresco vs Glide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29363321/picasso-v-s-imageloader-v-s-fresco-vs-glide)

Hope it will help :)